# Plotting density plots on the negative y axis with ggplot2, R

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot densities on both sides of the x axis - trying to visualize reads mapping to both strands of a genomic region.

I have two problems :

1. I want to use `ggplot2` but
2. I don't know how to extract the data from the plot object, or invert the plot that has already been made.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you provide a small reproducible example to help us understand what your question is? Or what your current code is?

Answer (score 6):

Your question is very unclear, but I found the "densities on both sides of the x axis" potentially interesting. So maybe you're trying to do something like this:

```
d <- data.frame(x = rnorm(1000),x1 = rnorm(1000,sd = 0.5))

ggplot(data = d,aes(x = x)) + 
    geom_density() + 
    geom_density(aes(x = x1,y = -(..density..)))
```

[image]